# Вызов сервиса из контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Есть контроллер , Action метод которого должен создавать задачу(их может быть много разных), и возвращать, сообщение, что либо задачу успешно создана, либо эта задача уже в работе запустить можно только 1 экземпляр 1 вида задачи задачи.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateTask([FromBody] CreateTaskDto createTaskDto)
{
    var command = new CreateTaskCommand()
    {
        Name = createTaskDto.Type.GetDisplayName(),
        Path = createTaskDto.Path,
        Type = createTaskDto.Type
    };

    var getExemplarTask = TaskCommander.Add(command.Type);
    if (getExemplarTask != null)
    {
        var vm = await Mediator.Send(command);

        getExemplarTask.Id = vm.Id;
        getExemplarTask?.Service.StartAsync(getExemplarTask.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
        
        return Ok(new AppResponse(message: $"Task {createTaskDto.Type.GetDisplayName()} succesfully created!", data: vm));
    }

    return Ok(new AppResponse(message: $"Task {createTaskDto.Type.GetDisplayName()} succesfully created!"));
}
```

в поле Type enum`ka с задачами

Так же есть второй Action метод, для прерывания задачи по Id задачи

```
[HttpGet("{Id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CancelTask(int Id)
{
    var command = new UpdateTaskCommand()
    {
        Id = Id,
        Status = Status.Canceled,
        FinishDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    TaskCommander.Cancel(Id);
    var vm = await Mediator.Send(command);

    return Ok(new AppResponse(message: $"Task {vm.Type.GetDisplayName()} succesfully canceled!", data: vm));
}
```

Пробовал создавать отдельный класс TaskController , в нем методы Add и Cancel и словарь типа IService | CancelationTokenSource (IService - интефейс реализуемый во всех сервисах).

При добавлении проверяем есть ли данная задача(по имени) в словаре, Если нет, то добавляем задачу, Через Task.Run(* , CancelationTokenSource.Token) запускаем и говорим медиатору ,чтобы сохранил в БД результат.

При удалении ищем в словаре так же по имени запущенный сервис, если он есть, то берем у него значение (CancelationTokenSource) и используем _cts.Cancel()

Однако эта конструкция работать оказалось. Столкнулся со следующими проблемами:

1. Из-за Task.Run сохранение в БД происходит очень медленно
2. Отмена задачи не происходит совсем

Вопрос: Как правильно реализовать создание и отмену задачи, а так же проверку на уникальность созданной задачи?

UPD:

Сам класс бизнес логики

```
public class CryptoFinderService : IService
{
    
    public CryptoFinderService()
    {
        
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        /// Просто иммитация работы
        while (true) 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("!!!!!");
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }
    }
}
```

класс для добавления и удаления задач

```
public static class TaskCommander
{
    private static List<ExemplarTask> _stackService = new();

    public static ExemplarTask? Add(TaskType type)
    {
        var service = SelectTask(type);

        var exemplar = new ExemplarTask()
        {
            Id = 0,
            Name = type.GetDisplayName(),
            Service = service,
            CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
        };

        var taskIsContains = _stackService
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .Any(x => x == exemplar.Name);

        if (taskIsContains)
        {
            return null;
        }

        _stackService.Add(exemplar);
        return exemplar;
    }

    public static void Cancel(int Id)
    {
        var exemplar = _stackService
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
        
        exemplar?.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
    
    public static IService SelectTask(TaskType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case TaskType.CryptoFinder:
                return new CryptoFinderService();

            default:
                throw new TaskNotFound(nameof(TaskType));
        }
    }

    public class ExemplarTask
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IService Service { get; set; }
        public CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }
    }
}
```

По моей логике класс TaskCommander должен руководить созданными задачами. Запускать и прерывать работу задач, но работать оно увы и ах не хочет

Comment: Не показали код сервиса, так сложно угадать будет

Comment: @OwDafuq дело не в сервисе. Дело в непонимании, как вызывать сервисы из контроллеров, чтобы не было тормозов. Данный момент сервис пустой и реализует лишь метод интерфейса async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cts) 

там просто while(true) Debug.WriteLine("1") для проверки запуска

Comment: Так это IHostedService? Почитайте как он работает сначала, while(true) в нем запустить - точно не то, что нужно делать

Comment: @OwDafuq да нет. Обычная бизнес логика. Задача может выполняться как 10 секунд, так и 10 часов. Поэтому важно, чтобы ответ о, том что задача запустилась должна придти сразу же. А сама задача пусть крутится сколько ей нужно

Comment: IHostedService так не работает, он должен вызываться при старте приложения, метод StartAsync не должен быть вечным (или многочасовым). Вы не правильно поняли для чего нужны IHostedServic'ы

Comment: @OwDafuq - вы сами себе противоречите: _он должен вызываться при старте приложения_ - _не должен быть вечным_.

Comment: По описанию всё сделано верно. Только неясно, зачем `Task.Run`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для того, чтобы не блокировать основной поток. Временное решение

Comment: А с чего ему блокироваться? Ведь долгая работа будет выполняться в фоновом сервисе.

Comment: `IService` - ваш собственный интерфейс? То есть это не `IHostedService`, как подумали мы с OwDafuq.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov конечно мой. Я OwDafuq это и ответил

Comment: Длительные задачи в ASP.NET в общем случае нельзя запускать в Тасках. В зависимости от того, что является хостом, такие задачи могут быть прекращены в любой момент. Например, IIS может выгрузить из памяти веб-приложение, к которому долго не было запросов. / Следует использовать [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, почитаю

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в таком случае каким образом вызвать этот сервис из контроллера? Есть ли в целом примеры вызова бизнес логики из контроллеров?

Простыми словами говоря у меня есть задача, к примеру секундомер, который я хочу запустить через контроллер и он будет выводит в дебаг консоль время, каждую секунду. 

Я отправляю запрос, запускается секундомер и мне приходит ответ "Секундомер запущен"

После чего я хочу выключить секундомер и отправляю другой запрос. Он выключает этот секундомер и посылает мне ответ "Секундомер остановлен"

Вот примерно такую логику пытаюсь сделать

Comment: Странный вопрос, конечно, создаете сервис, регистрируете его как singleton (под вашу задачу, видимо, он и нужен) и просто вызываете его в контроллере. Если есть проблемы с тем как регистрировать сервисы и получать их где-то в коде, то вам сюда - https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/6.1.php